# Civic R18A2 oil consumption

Tags: engine, honda, oil, civic

Looks like my Civic burned or lost 2L of oil in the past 6 months, I think that is excessive. At previous oil change garage mechanics advised me to use 5w30 viscosity oil because 0w30 is too thin. I used 5w30 just to see now that consumption is exaggerated.

I always used high quality oil and replaced it often ( twice per year, around 12000km between drains ). I fear bad/warn piston rings, I must admit that I drove the car at the limit sometimes, maybe more than needed, like revving the engine to the redline.  I fear bad rings because enigne always used a bit of oil like 1L per 10000.

Is there a chance for worn piston rings on an gasoline engine which has only 130.000km on it?

However, according to [this](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/12628/what-causes-an-engine-to-burn-oil) increasing to a thicker oil might increase oil consumption because of bad rings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many things wrong with what you are doing and what you have self diagnosed.

First, 0w-30 and 5w-30 are *the same weight oil*. Modifiers in the oil cause it to flow easier with the 0w than with the 5w *when the engine is cold*. If anything, you are hurting your engine by putting the 5w oil, than by using the 0w, because most engine wear occurs at startup of the engine. Since the 5w won't flow as quickly as the 0w would, you are keeping the engine without oil flow longer, causing more wear. No matter what else you do, go back to using the oil which is recommended for your vehicle. If that means 0w-30, then use it.

Second, while you say you are running only 10k per oil change, most vehicles recommend changing oil about every 5,000km or 3 months *which ever comes first*. You are basically doubling the oil change interval which adds to oil breakdown and causes more wear on your engine.

Third, 1L or oil per 10k is not a lot of oil to be using, especially considering what you've suggested in your question. More than likely in your case, your car is leaking more oil than it's consuming. (Check the fifth thing below.)

Fourth, most manufacturers have two different oil change intervals. One being for normal use and the other for severe use. Considering what you've suggested about "... *I drove the car at the limit sometimes, maybe more than needed, like revving the engine to the redline* ..." you are definitely using it in the "severe" use range. There is nothing inherently wrong with using your car in any manner you'd like, but if you're going to be taxing your vehicle, make sure you are treating it well in return.

Fifth, check the inside of the tail pipe for soot. Take your finger and rub it. If the soot which is there comes back greasy feeling, then your engine is burning oil. *This would be an indication of oil going out the tail pipe and bad rings which would be causing it.* If it's just a little black, then it shouldn't be a big deal. The engine may need a tune up.

Sixth, park your car on a clean piece of concrete (in the driveway works well). In the morning, pull your vehicle back and check for oil spots where it was parked. If you don't find any, that doesn't mean much. If you do find some spots of oil, you know you are leaking a little bit. Lift the hood and check around the engine (on, under, around ... be thorough). You are looking for any dirt buildup on the engine or anything which looks like leaking oil. Look around the valve cover (typical leak spot). Check your accessories for oil or grime buildup. Any of these would indicate you are losing oil through leakage and not through burning the oil.

As an aside, if you haven't done it yet, *get the timing belt changed*. If this has never been done, you are risking having to get a new engine regardless of if it's burning oil. If the belt should break or slip, your engine will encounter piston to valve contact, destroying at the very least the valves, if bad enough, could require an entire engine to fix.

Comment: Suet? Do you mean soot? :). Maybe it is just a term I have never heard?

Comment: @HandyHowie - You are right ... I always get the spelling mixed up. [Suet](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/suet) is the white fatty substance on animal meat. Corrected and thanks!

Comment: I thought this was interesting about oil changes -  http://www.edmunds.com/car-care/top-7-urban-legends-about-motor-oil.html

Comment: @HandyHowie - Well, I'll split the difference with you on 5k v 10k km interval change. The Honda manual for 2000-2006 (guessing since the OP didn't put the age of the vehicle in there) for severe duty use is 5k miles (or ~8k km). 10k km is a bit long to run. Most people do not realize they are in severe duty range, which also includes constant city driving. I'd put money on the vehicle losing oil through leakage versus bad rings. Honda engines are good and should last well into the 200k mile range if *minimum* maintenance is applied.

Comment: The severe maintenance interval is 5000miles( 8000km ). I was changing the oil at around 12000km. I agree that I am in sever driving conditions because of roads and the driving manner. Will clearly go back to 0w30.

Comment: Note that I don't have a timing belt, the engine runs with a chain belt that needs to be serviced at 200000miles. I haven't seen any oil spots under the car, would have to inspect it for leaks.

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  thanks for suggestions will check the exhaust pipe and the engine for leaks. Will also go back to 8000km interval drains, note that what I consider exaggerated is 2L for 5000km, which happened recently.

Comment: @BogdanPetrica - Good to hear about the chain ... I had to make some assumptions as to which year/engine your car had, so went with the prudent response. I don't want to see anybody get stranded on the side of the road because of something which is preventable. Leaks seem the most viable problem. Most vehicles tend to leak more while under stress than when sitting, at least my Silverado is that way. No spots on the ground and no blue smoke out the rear. The missing oil has to go somewhere if it isn't burning it (and it's not in the coolant either :o)

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 3 month or 5kkm oil changes for most cars? I've never heard this recommendation in my life, seems excessive.